# During wrangling my data I created the new table below. What do you call the first column? how can I find the number of unique values in it?

Tags: pandas, data-wrangling

What is that CustomerID called? is it index?

[copy of the codes and output can be find here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHFuh.png) Sorry! Stack overflow is not allowing me to just copy and paste the picture here yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [hierarchical-index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "foo": [1, 2, 3],
    "spam": [4, 5, 6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("foo")

uniques = len(df.index.unique("foo"))
print(uniques)

3
```

Comment: Sure, I will do!